# Black screen during setContentView execution

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

I have a `MainActivity`. Sometimes when it is loading I observe black screen for a second.
I measured timings for operations in `onCreate` method and discovered that more than one second was spent for `setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);`
I prefer to show previous screen (in my case Splash screen) instead of this black screen during `setContentView` execution. **How can I rid off this black screen?**

Seems android in some way preloads layouts and such problems occurs sometimes. But if I kill my process and start app I always see this black screen.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use a static variable to handle the `View` cache.
2. Use an `AsyncTask` to don't freeze your origin `Activity`
3. Use `LayoutInflater` to inflate the `View` layout and cache it
4. In the `onCreate()` of the target Activity set the cache

Something like this:

**Origin activity**

```
...
                //noinspection unchecked
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                                MainParentActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                        // VERY VERY SLOW action if your Activity is heavy
                        DialerActivity.cachedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialer_portrait, null, false);
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainParentActivity.this, DialerActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }.execute();

...
```

**Target activity**

```
public class DialerActivity extends MainParentActivity {
    static View cachedView = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (cachedView != null) {
            setContentView(cachedView);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.dialer_portrait);
        }
    }
 . . .
```

You can use also a ProgressDialog while inflating to avoid freeze sensation on the transition.